# Set margin top to a Crouton object Android

Tags: android, android-layout, crouton

Is there a way to set a margin top to a crouton ? (https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton)

Answer (score 3):

You can add a margin by adding a custom view with top margin to a Crouton like this:

`Crouton.make(getActivity(), myView);`

Comment: Thanks. And how can i create a custom view with a top margin with a minimum code ?

Comment: That's a separate question. Generally this can be looked up [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SizePaddingMargins).